# Struts html tag inside <script>

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2, ognl

I know that this is a very noob and dumb question, but I need help. Tried several topics and none's working.

So I'm trying to pass a List created in Struts2(java) into javascript to draw a chart using highlight. I've read several articles and come up with this:

```
$(function drawList() {
var list = [
<c:forEach items="${listFromJava}" var="alistFromJava">
{itemName: "${alistFromJava.attribute}"},
</c:forEach>
];
```

However it never works, and always ends up with:  Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.

If I try:

```
list = '<s:property value="listFromJava"/>
```

then it returns the reference only.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid confusion while googling:

[`<c:forEach` is **JSTL**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

[`${listFromJava}` is **EL**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

[`<s:property` is **STRUTS2 UI TAG**](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ui-tag-reference.html)

[`listFromJava` (or `%{listFromJava}`") is **OGNL**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ognl/info)

The Struts2 Tag that replaces JSTL's `forEach` [is `<s:iterator>`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html).

Your function may be rewritten in pure Struts2 like this:

```javascript
$(function drawList() {
    var list = [
        <s:iterator value="listFromJava" >
            {itemName: '<s:property escapeJavascript="true" value="attribute"/>'},
        </s:iterator>
    ];
});
```

To prevent the last element to have an undesidered comma, use `<s:if>`

```javascript
$(function drawList() {
    var list = [
        <s:iterator value="listFromJava" status="stat">
            <s:if test="#stat.index>0">,</s:if>
            {itemName: '<s:property escapeJavascript="true" value="attribute"/>'}
        </s:iterator>
    ];
});
```

**EDIT**: added the escaping needed to prevent javascript injection issues (`escapeJavascript="true"`).

Comment: thanks @Andrea Ligios, however idk why the struts UI tag <s:iterator> seems not to be readable.
I end up with the stuff like this:
    var length = ('<s:property value="%{listFromJava.size()}"/>');
It works, but the problem is I have to get each element in the list by hardcode, like:
    var aValue = ('<s:property value="%{listFromJava[0].PROPERTY}"/>')
I tried this:
    var aValue[i] = ('<s:property value="%{listFromJava['+i+'].PROPERTY}"/>')
but no luck. Any idea?
Again, thank you very much for responding.

Comment: 1) The SO editor and the Eclipse JSP editor are not advanced enough to right interpret and color the OGNL syntax: it *seems* wrong, but it definitely is right;

Comment: 2) You can't mix javascript variables (evaluated client side) with Struts tags (evaluated server side, then before). Have you tried the solution i posted ? Look at the source, it should be what you need. Alternatively, you can specify the index manually: `<s:property value="listFromJava[%{#stat.index}].attribute"/>`

Comment: thank you so much. it really works, and yes, the editor can not recognize the code :)